# How to find Current User and Organization Details in Servicenow

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

How can i get below details of loggedin user via Rest API from servicenow?

```
1.Userprofile informations
2.Organization details
```

Answer (score 0):

`gs.getUser()` has all the information:

```
gs.getUser().getFullName()
gs.getUser().getDepartmentID();
gs.getUser().getCompanyID();
```

Comment: @georgeawg  and Naveen how to use the above function in REST API call. For eg:  Similar to following query ,  
  https://instance.service-now.com/api/now/table/sys_user?sysparm_query=sys_id=javascript:gs.getUserID()                                                              i need to form for  gs.getUser() and the others.

Comment: Go to Scripted REST APIs  - in the respective method script add these and check.

Comment: Could you please suggest with normal REST API.Because we are not going to use  scripted REST API.

Comment: GET http://instance.service-now.com/api/now/ui/user/current_user . 
will get the user_sys_id and user_name etc.
Using this you can get further details - GET http://localhost:8080/api/now/table/sys_user?sysparm_limit=1&sys_id='replace from above'

Comment: With the above api i am able to get user details.Please suggest how to find under which organization the user belongs to?.

Comment: You mean department. All information is there in the second get call.

Comment: No.I need the Organization ID. Organization ID is the account level identifier among users.

Comment: I only see company attribute for the user. No other organisation related information